# Whom Did Jacob's Sons Marry (Jubilees 34)?

Tags: marriage, apocrypha, twelve-tribes

The non-biblical book of [Jubilees chapter 34](https://www.sefaria.org/Book_of_Jubilees?tab=contents) (c. 2nd c. b.c.e.) preserves a tradition about the wives of Jacob's sons:

> 20. And after Joseph perished, the sons of Jacob took unto themselves wives. The name of Reuben's wife is ’Adâ and the name of Simeon's
>     wife is ’Adîbâ’a, a Canaanite; and the name of Levi's wife is Mêlkâ,
>     of the daughters of Aram, of the seed of the sons of Terah; and the
>     name of Judah's wife, Bêtasû’êl, a Canaanite; and the name of
>     Issachar's wife, Hêzaqâ; and the name of Zebulon's wife, †Nî’îmân†;
>     and the name of Dan's wife, ’Êglâ; and the name of Naphtali's wife,
>     Rasû’û, of Mesopotamia; and the name of Gad's wife, Mâka; and the name
>     of Asher's wife, ’Îjônâ; and the name of Joseph's wife, Asenath,  the
>     Egyptian; and the name of Benjamin's wife, ’Îjasaka. 21. And Simeon
>     repented, and took a second wife from Mesopotamia as his brothers (did).

I'm aware of biblical confirmation of only one these: Joseph's wife Asenath of Egypt (Gen. 41:45). The identity of Judah's wife (prior to Tamar) is given as the daughter of Shua in Gen. 38:1, and this could be the same person as  Bêtasû’êl. Are there biblical or other ancient references that shed light on the supposed wives of the Israelite tribal leaders?

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be anything further to what you have already discovered in the Bible. Once in the realms of tradition, there can be no assurance but only legends and accounts that have emerged from shadowy realms of supposition. They could be correct, of course, but unless some expert in ancient Jewish history and genealogy can answer, there is no telling.

This question might get some good answers if asked in they Mi Yodeya site.